# Polymer app best practices

Tags: web, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component, polymerfire

I have best practices questions to respect while developing Polymer Web App.

Let's say I have a Todo app. The main element `my-main-task` is responsible for switching between those elements: `list` all tasks, `view` a single task, create a `new` task, `edit` a task and `delete` a task.

My question is: the `new` element must save data using `firebase-document` or `iron-ajax` by itself or delegate it to the `my-main-task`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the recent Polymer Summit (London 2016), there was a lot of talk of being *lazy* (as in lazy loading). This means, that you only load/render what you need and (in the best case) nothing else.

**This said, the short answer to your question is:** the `new` element should save the data by itself, as it is the most appropriate place to do so.

As for the long answer, bear with me for a while.

On the [Google Developer's Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/) page, there is actually an architectural pattern named [The App Shell Model](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/architecture/app-shell). This pattern actually describes your `my-main-task` element.

Some useful quotes:

> The app "shell" is the minimal HTML, CSS and JavaScript required to power the user interface /.../
>
> /.../ In general, your app should load the simplest shell possible but include enough meaningful page content with the initial download.

This being said, it is unwise to put the logic for saving a new item into the app shell element (in your case the `my-main-task` element).

To go even further, let's have a look at the Polymer's sample [Shop app](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/toolbox/case-study) ([Github repo](https://github.com/Polymer/shop),  [Online demo](https://shop.polymer-project.org/)).

If you look at the "app shell" element `shop-app` ([source code](https://github.com/Polymer/shop/blob/master/src/shop-app.html)), you can see that it only implements the following:

- basic page layout (sidebar, content)
- routing
- cart data
- cart logic

In this particular case, the cart data and logic is put into the shell element, since it is used across all of the pages, but otherwise *no* other business logic is implemented there.

**As for the long answer to your question**, let's take a look at the Checkout page, namely the `shop-checkout` element ([source code](https://github.com/Polymer/shop/blob/master/src/shop-checkout.html)). You can see, that all form related data (i.e. posting to the server) is done within this element and nothing is delegated to the app shell element.

Another example is the `shop-list` element ([source code](https://github.com/Polymer/shop/blob/master/src/shop-list.html)). Again, you can see that this element retrieves the data by itself and only interacts with the app shell element to change the section.

To conclude, let's name another good practice that is also contained in the aforementioned Shop app, which is **the way the data flows within the app**. There was an interesting talk at the Polymer Summit ([Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAW4YDLtPVs)) regarding this, and the essence is the following: use one-way data bindings as much as possible and try to avoid two-way data bindings unless really necessary. To achieve this, the *downward* data flow (parent to child) should be done as a one-way data binding, and the *upward* data flow (child to parent) should be done as an event. This is essential for element reusability since the coupling between the elements is much lower.